# Unable to parse the unicode character

Tags: c#, filestream, xmlreader

I am trying to read the xml file using xml reader. I have created a dictionary to store the mime-type and its corresponding extension. I have stored the mime-type in this format. `<MimeToExtension MimeType="image/x‑portable‑bitmap" Extension=".pbm" />`.

When I try to fetch the value form dictionary using the key `"image/x‑portable‑bitmap"`. It doesn't return any value. Because `"image/x-portable-bitmap"` is saved as

[image: When pasted the value in notepad++]

The `-` character is changed into square brackets. How can I resolve this?

```
FileStream filestream = File.OpenRead(mimeTypeToExtension);
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filestream))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (reader.HasAttributes && reader.AttributeCount == 2)
            {
                string extension = reader.GetAttribute(0);
                string mimeType = reader.GetAttribute(1);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mimeType) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension) &&
                    !fileTypes.ContainsKey(extension))
                    fileTypes.Add(extension, mimeType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you _enter_ the `x-portable-bitmap` value? The squares indicate that they aren't "hyphen-minus", but [another dash character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm), and the reader fails to detect the encoding. Using the proper encoding won't fix the issue, as the value will be unusable: browsers won't be able to handle it. Fix the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you propably copy and pasted the mime type from somewhere on the internet and got the wrong hyphen.

You hyphen is a **non-breaking-hyphen** (Unicode 0x2011). You want a **regular** hyphen (Unicode 0x2d). Just manually replace all hyphens in your code or just copy this:

```
"image/x-portable-bitmap"
```

Always be careful when copying code/text/etc. from the internet. This issue often occurs with quotes too, because most CMS don't account for programmers' needs and just replace some characters to make them "look better" or to avoid formatting issues.